# How to log off from RemoteApp Session from User Computer

Tags: windows, remoteapp

We use RemoteApp for all our Home office clients.

Sometimes the users need to log off from their RemoteApp Session, for various reasons.

Now for RemoteApps, you only have the possibility to `terminate the connection` on your Desktop. This results in a `connection terminated` on the Server, but their session is still there. This isn't really logged off because whenever you start any RemoteApp again, your session from before is reopened.

I can do a real log off on the server for each user by right-clicking their connection and say `log off`. Then the connection completely disappears from the connection panel and when they open a RemoteApp on their desktop, a completely new session is created.

Does anybody know a real log off that the user can perform himself is possible, without me needing to log them off on the server?

I know they could do cmd -> `shutdown -l` etc. but my users aren't very good with computers and that would be too complicated for them.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user can press Ctrl-Alt-End while interacting with the remote app, and select Log Off.

Answer (score 0):

looks like if you want to do this you need to publish `logoff.exe` as a RemoteApp. I did not find any other solution.

Here's a PowerShell Command that does that (change Value of CollectionName and Connectionbroker Parameters):

```
New-RDRemoteApp -CollectionName CollectionName -DisplayName Logoff -Connectionbroker ServerFQDN -IconIndex 27 -IconPath "c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll" -ShowInWebAccess $true -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\logoff.exe"
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8cd3792-1de7-4ec3-9bbb-d1063b04aef4/log-off-from-remote-apps?forum=winserverTS

Answer (score 0):

Use Session Time Limits in Group Policy to manage this. There's specifically a setting for logging off a disconnected RemoteApp session.

Comment: sounds great, but sometimes it's good when the session is kept alive after terminating the connection. Only occasionally i need it to be shut down directly. So this would not work for my case.